# generate database & tables schema (ddl) on Oracle pl-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, oracle, oracle10g, data-migration

Anyone have a PL-SQL statement that i can use to generate database & tables schema for specific database on Oracle 10g? I need the schema in .sql file and if possible compatible with ANSI-92/99 sql implementation, so i can use the generated .sql directly on sql server 2005.

Already heard about exp/imp, but it seems generated dump file, what i need just a simple ddl on .sql file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote [oraddlscript](http://devio.wordpress.com/2009/10/25/introducing-oraddlscript/) which calls dbms_metadata.get_ddl (Pop's answer) for each database object owned by a user and writes the DDL to a file.

Update: [Answered comment](http://devio.wordpress.com/2009/11/04/oraddlscript-solving-odp-net-version-conflicts/)

Comment: using oracle 10.2 and can't connect, try replacing dll with the one shipped with oracle and throw exception

Comment: I tried on a non-development machine, and got an exceptions. Solved after installing ODAC 11.1.0.6.21 with "install.bat all c:\oracle\odp odac". ODAC is here: http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/windows/odpnet/index.html.

Comment: Can I get the DDL for tables owned by a different user? For example, my user is "A", I want tables from schema/user "B". I *can* query simple data (SELECT * FROM  B.TABLE_I_WANT) , but I get a failure  `ORA-31603: object "TABLE_I_WANT" of type TABLE not found in schema "B"` when I try to get_ddl('TABLE', 'TABLE_I_WANT', 'B'). Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE',table_name,owner)
from dba_tables where owner='schema name';
```

It returns longs, so you may want to play with the long buffer.

More about `dbms_metadata` here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_metada.htm

Comment: already tested use long 90000, but the generated script was unusable since it contain much blank and unterminated strings

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to dump your schema, this free package does a very nice job.  We use it in daily production.

> http://sourceforge.net/projects/cx-oracletools

If you need to convert from Oracle to SQL Server, this software might do a better job.  We've used it to convert between Oracle, MySql, and Postgreqsql.

> http://www.spectralcore.com/fullconvert

Comment: it's only for oracle9i? i use oracle 10.2 (10g)

Comment: No problem for 10.2, that's what we have also.

Answer (score 1):

Greetings, I'd recomend using [Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/datamodeler/index.html) since it's from Oracle, it can read the DDL information directly from the Data Dictionary.  It creates an ERD and then you can produce DDL for SQL Server 2000/2005, some versions of DB2 and Oracle 9i/10g/11g.