# Efficient way to obtain DDL from entire Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ddl

Currently there are about 30 tables in the Oracle 11.1 database.

Is there a way to generate all ddl with a single command? (Or a few commands?)

**Edit:**
Following a suggestion below, I tried:

```
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl( 'TABLE', table_name, owner )
  FROM all_tables;
```

And got:

```
ORA-31603: object "HS_PARTITION_COL_NAME" of type TABLE not found in schema "SYS"
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 105
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 3241
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 4812
ORA-06512: at line 1
31603. 00000 -  "object \"%s\" of type %s not found in schema \"%s\""
*Cause:    The specified object was not found in the database.
*Action:   Correct the object specification and try the call again.
```

It's clear that there is something extremely basic about `dbms_metadata` that I don't understand.

Comment: possible duplicate of [generate database & tables schema (ddl) on Oracle pl-sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628541/generate-database-tables-schema-ddl-on-oracle-pl-sql)

Comment: I'm sorry about similarity between this and other questions, I don't understand the answers of the other questions. (Or this one, yet.)

Comment: In your edit, you need a WHERE condition that limits the query to generating the DDL only for the 30 tables you want DDL for.  It doesn't make sense to try to generate DDL for tables owned by `SYS`.

Comment: I guess I need a clue on the where clause.

Comment: If you know the schemas that your tables are in, use something like "where owner in ('SCHEMA1', 'SCHEMA2', 'SCHEMA3')", replacing the SCHEMA1 etc with the actual schema names.

Comment: Can I get the DDL for tables owned by a different user? For example, my user is "A", I want tables from schema/user "B". I *can* query simple data (SELECT * FROM  B.TABLE_I_WANT) , but I get a failure  `ORA-31603: object "TABLE_I_WANT" of type TABLE not found in schema "B"` when I try to get_ddl('TABLE', 'TABLE_I_WANT', 'B'). Thoughts?

Comment: @TheRedPea I'd recommend you ask a new question. Not many will be reading the comments of four year old questions. I'm notified as the OP, but I certainly don't know.

Comment: Thanks. I considered asking new question. I may still. But I strongly suspect a permissions issue on my part. GET_DDL probably requires specific permissions. I think I am able to use this Wizard to get what I need: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/export-intro-1-161239.html Thanks again.

Comment: Indeed that wizard works. In the exported output it says: 
`-- Unable to render TABLE DDL for object AP.AP_INVOICE_DISTRIBUTIONS_ALL with DBMS_METADATA attempting internal generator.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what worked for me:

```
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', table_name)
  FROM user_tables;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [DBMS_METADATA package](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_metada.htm).  Something like

```
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl( 'TABLE', table_name, owner )
  FROM all_tables
 WHERE <<some condition to get the 30 tables in question>>
```

Comment: +1: Nice example.. DBA_TABLES might be more appropriate, depending on privs of user runnning query

Comment: @Craig I don't understand your comment. Where would `DBA_TABLE` go? What effect would it have?

Comment: @FarmBoy - The `DBA_TABLES` view has data about every table in the database but you may not have access to `DBA_TABLES`.  The `ALL_TABLES` view has data about every table that you have access to.  The `USER_TABLES` view has data about every table that you own.  You can use those three views more or less interchangably depending on exactly what data you're looking for.  I guessed that you probably have access to the 30 tables you're trying to get DDL for so I used `ALL_TABLES`.

Comment: Would `USER_TABLES` allow me to omit a where clause?

Comment: @FarmBoy - If you want to get the DDL for every table that you own (i.e. you own the 30 tables in question), yes.  `USER_TABLES` does not have an `OWNER` column so you'd need to hard-code the owner in the call to `DBMS_METADATA`

Comment: @Justin - You could also omit the owner in the call to DBMS_METADATA, as it defaults to the current user

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can pretty easily using the [dbms_metadata](http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_dbms_metadata.htm) package. You can write a routine that opens a cursor on the `USER_TABLES` system table and gets the ddl for each table. An example for that is in the article too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to individually generate ddl for each object,

Queries are:

```
--GENERATE DDL FOR ALL USER OBJECTS
--1. FOR ALL TABLES

SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE', TABLE_NAME) FROM USER_TABLES;

--2. FOR ALL INDEXES

SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('INDEX', INDEX_NAME) FROM USER_INDEXES WHERE INDEX_TYPE ='NORMAL';

--3. FOR ALL VIEWS

SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('VIEW', VIEW_NAME) FROM USER_VIEWS;

OR

SELECT TEXT FROM USER_VIEWS

--4. FOR ALL MATERILIZED VIEWS

SELECT QUERY FROM USER_MVIEWS

--5. FOR ALL FUNCTION

SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('FUNCTION', OBJECT_NAME) FROM USER_PROCEDURES WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'FUNCTION'
```

---

**GET_DDL** Function doesnt support for some object_type like LOB,MATERIALIZED VIEW, TABLE PARTITION

SO, Consolidated query for generating DDL will be:

```
SELECT OBJECT_TYPE, OBJECT_NAME,DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL(OBJECT_TYPE, OBJECT_NAME, OWNER) FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE (OWNER = 'XYZ') AND OBJECT_TYPE NOT IN('LOB','MATERIALIZED VIEW', 'TABLE PARTITION') ORDER BY OBJECT_TYPE, OBJECT_NAME;
```